# MVVM: What to do when a service call fails

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I have WP7 app that uses the MVVM pattern. When the user goes from page to page within the app, I have to call a WCF service to get data.

This works all fine. But what do I do, when the service call fails?

Right now I do a `MessageBox.Show("Some error message.");` inside the view model, but shouldn't this somehow be done within the view? How would I do this?  With a databinding? How?

I would also like to navigate back if the service calls fails:

```
if ( NavigationService.CanGoBack ) { NavigationService.GoBack(); }
```

But how would I implement this inside the view with MVVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the Caliburn Micro MVVM framework, with it you can deal with these problems in the following ways.

Notifications from the view model can be done in a number of different ways, if you make use of Coroutines in CM then you can create a NotificationResult that interacts with the separately from the View Model. Another approach is to have some sort of Notification Source view model that is bound to a Notification control in the View. I have some sample code for this approach at [Windows Phone 7 Notification Control](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/windows-phone-7-notification-control).

Again in the CM framework there is an INavigationService interface that you can declare as a dependency of your view model and do the navigation through that. The benefit of this is that it's all unit testable.

Comment: Thanks, your "Notification Control" helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the developers of Catel, which is an open-source MVVM framework. We support several services that contains both a real and test implementation of the services. This way, if you need to show a message box, you can do this:

```
var messageService = GetService<IMessageService>();
messageService.Show("This is a message");
```

Of course, in the unit test version of this service, no actual message box will be shown, but you can add expected results so you can actually test a user answering OK or cancel.

Same for the navigation service:

```
var navigationService = GetService<INavigationService>();
navigationService.Navigate("/UI/Pages/MyNewPage.xaml");
// OR
navigationService.Navigate<MyViewModel>();
```

In my opinion, this is the way you need to go, and good frameworks like Caliburn.Micro and Catel support this out of the box.